# Connecting directly to a specific instance in service fabric

Tags: .net, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have an game server backend service currently running on an Azure Cloud Service, and looking to port this to run on Service Fabric instead. I've ran into a problem that I can't seem to solve.

In the old Cloud Service version of the backend, we had the ability to connect directly to a specific worker role from our game clients, using the following:

1. Configure an InstanceInputEndPoint with a local port and a public port range

`<InstanceInputEndpoint name="GameServer" protocol="udp" localPort="10000">
        <AllocatePublicPortFrom>
          <FixedPortRange min="10000" max="10999" />
        </AllocatePublicPortFrom>
      </InstanceInputEndpoint>`

2. Getting the private ip:port to bind a socket to via:

`RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["GameServer"].IPEndpoint;`

3. With some additional configuration values to supply the reserved IP public ip address of the cloud service we could also calculate the public ip:port that clients should connect to after being assigned to a game server instance.

`var publicAddress = IPAddress.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("PublicAddress"));
        var publicPort = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["GameServer"].PublicIPEndpoint.Port;
        return new IPEndPoint(publicAddress, publicPort);`

My current problem is simply that I see no way in service fabric to replicate this setup, basically to let me tell a client "connect directly to this specific instance of my game server service".

Comment: May I ask why you need/want this behavior? Are we talking about a stateless or stateful service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are trying to migrate an existing application to service fabric you could follow the steps described below. If you are creating a new application however, you should consider using a [reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy).

1. Configure the ServiceManifest.xml and clustermanifest.
   In the ServiceManifest.xml file you have to create an endpoint within the resouces tag. Note that udp is not supported as standard protocol here, but only http, https and tcp. By not providing a port number Service Fabric will automatically assign an available port from the available application ports.

   ```
   <Endpoints>
       <Endpoint Name="GameServer" Protocol="http" />
   </Endpoints>
   ```

   The application ports are configured in the cluster manifest under nodetypes:

   ```
   "applicationPorts": {
       "startPort": "10000",
       "endPort": "10999"
   }
   ```
2. Create the listening address. In order to get the port number for the listener you can use the service context:

   ```
   int port = Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoint("GameServer").Port;
   ```

   You can create your listening address using the following format:

   ```
   string listeningAddress = $"http://+:{port}/{applicationName}/";
   ```

   This is assuming you are using a stateless service. If you are using a stateful service you should add:

   ```
   StatefulServiceContext ssc = (StatefulServiceContext) Context;
   listeningAddress += ssc.PartitionId + "/" + ssc.ReplicaId + "/";
   ```
3. Your publish address should contain your socket protocol and IP address:

   ```
   string publishAddress = listeningAddress.Replace("+", FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN);
   publishAddress = publishAddress.Replace("http", "ws");
   ```

You can find more information on listeners on the [microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services#service-fabric-in-azure).

Comment: That's @Wouter B that's exactly what I was looking for...